# What does '*** Oldest frame' mean in ipdb?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdb, ipdb

I am trying to make http requests to a server and examine the content I get back. However, when I try poking around the `HTTPResponse object` with `ipdb`, I keep getting `*** Oldest frame` and I cant run any of the functions on the object that I should be able to run. Here is the block of code doing to fetching, and the `ipdb` output:

**code block:**

```
for acc in sp_lost:
    url = 'http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=mnemonic%3a'+acc+'+active%3ayes&format=tab&columns=entry%20name'
    u = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    ipdb.set_trace()
```

**ipdb output:**

```
ipdb> url
'http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=mnemonic%3aSPATL_MOUSE+active%3ayes&format=tab&columns=entry%20name'
ipdb> u
*** Oldest frame
ipdb> str(u)
'<http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0xe58e2d0>'
ipdb> type(u)
<class 'http.client.HTTPResponse'>
ipdb> u.url                      
*** Oldest frame
ipdb> u.url()         # <-- unable to run url() on object...?
*** Oldest frame
ipdb>
```

What does the `*** Oldest frame` mean, and how can I get this object into something more useful that I can run the appropriate functions on?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`u` is the PDB command to traverse stack frames. You are in the 'uppermost' frame already. `help u` will tell you more about it:

> ```
> u(p)
> Move the current frame one level up in the stack trace
> (to an older frame).
> ```

The command is closely related to `d(own)` and `w(here)`:

> ```
> d(own)
> Move the current frame one level down in the stack trace
> (to a newer frame).
> w(here)
> Print a stack trace, with the most recent frame at the bottom.
> An arrow indicates the "current frame", which determines the
> context of most commands.  'bt' is an alias for this command.
> ```

If you want to print the variable `u`, prefix it with a `!` to have it not interpreted by the debugger as a debug command:

```
!u
!u.url
```

or use `print()`:

```
print(u)
```

From the `help pdb` output:

> Commands that the debugger doesn't recognize are assumed to be Python
>   statements and are executed in the context of the program being
>   debugged.  Python statements can also be prefixed with an exclamation
>   point ('!').

`Oldest frame` is the frame in the stack where your program started; it is the oldest in time; the `Newest frame`, the other end of the stack, is where Python is executing code and is the current frame of execution, where Python would continue if you hit the `c(ontinue)` command.

A little demo with a recursive function:

```
>>> def foo():
...     foo()
... 
>>> import pdb
>>> pdb.run('foo()')
> <string>(1)<module>()
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> <stdin>(1)foo()
(Pdb) s
> <stdin>(2)foo()
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> <stdin>(1)foo()
(Pdb) s
> <stdin>(2)foo()
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> <stdin>(1)foo()
(Pdb) w
  /Users/mj/Development/Libraries/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/bdb.py(400)run()
-> exec cmd in globals, locals
  <string>(1)<module>()
  <stdin>(2)foo()
  <stdin>(2)foo()
> <stdin>(1)foo()
(Pdb) u
> <stdin>(2)foo()
(Pdb) u
> <stdin>(2)foo()
(Pdb) u
> <string>(1)<module>()
(Pdb) u
> /Users/mj/Development/Libraries/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/bdb.py(400)run()
-> exec cmd in globals, locals
(Pdb) u
*** Oldest frame
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Pieters, informative and thorough explanation as always :)